# How would I click a link that changes dynamically, with no id, but is always in the first cell of tbody?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The link I want is always here first link of `<tbody>`. But maybe called something different.

If you could maybe explain what the code is doing that would be cool too. The simpler the code the better because I have to wrap it into an Applescript.

[image: example]

Comment: Is it the first link on the page? Is it the first table on the page?

Comment: Hello Brandon, what is the function `offerResponse`? Could you paste some code as text into the question? And also, is there any actual error, I mean, what happens when you click it?

Comment: I believe it is actually the second table on the page. There a thead right above it and then above all that a bit there is a <table></table> with a body in it.

Comment: offerresponse brings up a layover popup. There is no error, clicking the link does what is expected. I am just trying to click it programatically. I am trying to write an apple script program that finds the first link in that table and clicks on it by way of javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could accomplish this with the following code based on your comments in your question and my answer.

```
document.querySelector('.odd').querySelector('a').click();
```

To provide a more permanent solution, more of the pages layout will need to be exposed.

**What this does**

`document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll` queries the element nodes on the DOM. The first option will pull the first instance it finds for the search value, while the second will return all in a nodelist.

Running the `click()` function will simulate a click on that element you have queried for.

Knowing this, you can now take this example and potentially make a working script for yourself.

Let me know if this helps you out. Since you state the layout always stays the same, this should get you started.

Comment: So it is very very close. `document.querySelectorAll('table')[2].querySelector('a').click()` gets me the first link of the <thead> of that table, directly above the link I want in the <tbody>

Comment: Edited my answer to the one that will help you out.

Comment: I really appreciate it. The adding of the [*any number] after ('a') doesn't seem to find anything. I could certainly show more of the table or the page if you think it would be beneficial.

Comment: @Brandon - Keep in mind I didn't just add a number, I changed the end part to `querySelectorAll` from `querySelector`

Comment: What line is the link on in that link? :)

Comment: @Brandon - Cheers, updated the answer. Should be fine now. Since this is the first class that appears as 'odd' as the class name, we select that and select the first link from it.

Comment: You're a rockstar that is going to make my Fiances life much easier! If there is some way I can buy you coffee or a beer shoot me a pm!

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an excellent situation to use find() since you'll always know the parent. Alternately adding a class to the anchor element would let you address it without crawling around the DOM.

```
$('.odd').find('a');
```